# Adding a constant to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find p(A) if p(x) = $2x^2 - x + 1$ where A is the below matrix:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 1 \\
        2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

**Attempt at a solution**

p(A) = $2 \cdot A^2 - A + 1\cdot A^0$

$A^2$ is below:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        11 & 4 \\
        8 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

However, what do I do with that plus one? I figured I can just pretend there is an $x^0$ next to 1 over there. Then I would sort of have A to the power of 0. Does this mean I will make every element of A into 1's and then add that as a matrix to the rest of the equation?

Comment: As you said, it is $A^0=I_n=id$.

Comment: The constant terms in the polynomial is normally translated into a multiple of the identity matrix. In this case, you would add $I$ to your sum. If you need to add some other constant, say $c$, then you would add the corresponding multiple of the identity, $cI$.

Comment: plus $1$ is to plus $I$. You might want to learn the concept of characteristic/minimal polynomial, helps to simplify your problem. I recommend you to Gantmacher's Theory of Matrices Vol.1.

Answer (score 1):

$cA_{n\times n}^0 = cI_{n\times n}$, where $c$ is the constant term. In your case, $c=1$, so we add the $2\times 2$ identity matrix to replace $1$.

Your final function evaluated at $A$ is given by $$p(A) = 2A^2 - A + I_{2\times 2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the example to the 
*Cayley-Hamilton-Theorem*, see the wikipedia article, with the matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2 \\ 3& 4 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
The theorem $p(A)=0$ can only hold with $A^0=I_n$.